Number of ways to write $n$ as $n=1\times a_{1}+2\times a_{2}+\cdots +n\times a_{n}$
There are for sure more than $n$ ways to write a positive integer $n$ as $n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ia_{i}$ with $a_{i}\in\mathbb{N}$. But I have no idea how to find the exact number of ways since $n+1=1\times \left( a_{1}+1\right) +\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n}ia_{i}$ and $n+1=\left( n+1\right) \times 1$ increases by $1$ the numbers of ways for $n+1$, but don't give all the possible ways for $n+1$. Thank you for your help !

Can you list out all of the ways for $n = 4$? I believe that there are $> 4$ ways. And if that's true, find the number of ways for $n = 5, 6, 7$ to try to establish a pattern.

I found $4=1\times 4=1\times 2+2\times 1=1\times 1+3\times 1=4\times 1$ @CalvinLin

There's also $  4 = 1 \times 0 + 2 \times 2$. From what I can tell, that should be counted.

You're right. So my guess is completely wrong. Thank you so much @CalvinLin

My recommendation is for you to calculate a few more initial values, and then enter them into OEIS to get a match. This is a well known sequence. $\quad$ Spoiler: There is no known closed form expression.

@abomasnow Yes, and that gives the generating function too (with the product to infinity).

This is a restatement of the number of partitions of n - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition . This is a very well-studied sequence but there is no closed-form expression for it.

@MichaelLugo: partitions only contain sums. This question contains sums of multiplications.

@Dominique Why not? A partition of a non-negative integer n, also called an integer partition, is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. You are allowed to repeat positive integers. You can then convert it into the form of $ n = \sum i a_i$, where $a_i$ counts the number of times we use the positive integer $i$ in the partition.
